# Get-AzureStorageAccount is not returning premium accounts (only standard accounts)

Tags: powershell, azure

Does anyone know why the Azure PowerShell cmdlet Get-AzureStorageAccount only returns standard storage accounts? I have two standard and two premium storage accounts in my one Azure subscription, and the cmdlet doesn't return the two premium ones.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Get-AzureStorageAccount does return information on premium storage accounts - I tried it on Azure PowerShell v1.3 and it was possible to create a Premium Storage account and retrieve its information.

Have you ensured that the Premium Storage accounts are in the subscription you are querying?

Comment: I would expect the cmdlet should return all the storage accounts. All my four storage accounts belong to the same subscription -- I only have one. I'm running this from a Windows 10 x64 box -- I'll try on another machine and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you created the storage account, classic or the new site?

If on the new, try Get-AzureRmStorageAccount command.